# How to get the intent Intent.ACTION_VIEW but not the Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent

In android. Some app declare both the ACTION_VIEW and ACTION_SEND in the intent-filter. I want to get all the ACTION_VIEW app but not the ACTION_SEND. Is it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search for `ACTION_SEND` and `ACTION_VIEW` and check through loop which app has both and exclude them from list.

```
public ArrayList<ResolveInfo> getApps() {
    ArrayList<ResolveInfo> result = new ArrayList<>();

    Intent view = new Intent();
    view.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    view.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("sdcard/blah/blah/blah")), "*/*");

    Intent send = new Intent();
    send.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    send.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("sdcard/blah/blah/blah")), "*/*");

    PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> actionView = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(view, 0);
    List<ResolveInfo> actionSend = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(send, 0);

    for (ResolveInfo viewItem : actionView) {
        boolean notFound = true;

        for (ResolveInfo sendItem : actionSend) {

            if (viewItem.activityInfo.name.equals(sendItem.activityInfo.name))
                notFound = false;

            if (notFound)
                result.add(viewItem);
        }
    }


    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But it seems not work for me. My Code is:
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
startActivity(intent);

By this way, it call some app is what I don't need. I want to filter these app.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very kind of you. I have tried the similar way before. But I think it is a little inefficient, and the point is after that I didn't find the right way to launch the activity by the ResolveInfo List. So I am looking for if there is any interfaces first. But you still give me a clear direction. I will try to find out some way to startActivity by ResolveInfo List

Comment: @donald im afraid that not possible.  there is one way to know what app and activity have what intent filter,  and that way is a long way! You have to open apps manifest and decode it.  Android known this as security issue that why we can't see this information. But if you good with that long way,  it's possible